# the xcode always run an anterior version of the app

Tags: ios, xcode, hybrid-mobile-app

I developed an hybrid application and I'm using the xcode to install it on my Ipad but when I made modifications and tried to installa the new version it always run the first version I installed in my Ipad and not the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the application and install a new one. Plus if you are taking build by archiving please select the new version you just builded.

Comment: I'm running the application from the xcode. And I tried to delete and reinstall the application but it didn't make any change

Comment: make sure you are selecting the correct target as well

Comment: Delete the Derived Data and run the app again, if there is no new entry in Derived Data. Do check Preferences/Locations/Derived Data and check if Legacy is selected. Selecting Unique will fix the problem.

Comment: Let me know if it works else we will find some other solution

Comment: The "Unique" was already selected. And I deleted the derived data but nothing changed :/ 
What do you mean by selecting the correct target ?

Comment: In project navigator select your xcode file and the menu that opens against it select the right target in left top corner

Comment: Sorry... nothing changed :/